# using Java String replace method produces different result than expected, why?

Tags: java, string, replace, substring, uppercase

I have the following code to capitalize first letter of word.
when I try to condense my key function in a one-liner I see that it is not working as expected.
here is the code;

```
import java.util.*;
public class CapitalizeName {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      String name="My naMe is ALex";
      String words="";
      String[] names=name.split(" ");
      for (String w: names) {
         w=w.toUpperCase(); //line 8
         w=w.replace(w.substring(1), w.substring(1).toLowerCase());  //line 9    
         //this single liner doesnot work:
         //w=w.toUpperCase().replace(w.substring(1), w.substring(1).toLowerCase());
        words+=w+" ";
      }
      System.out.println(words.trim());
     }  
    }
```

output is :

> My Name Is Alex

When I comment out the line 8 and line 9 and uncomment line 9 making a one liner, I get the following unexpected output:MY NAME IS ALEX.
Any help is appreciated?

Comment: A tip, one liners are something to avoid usually.  Yes, they're compact, but are more cryptic and harder to debug. Code you can read and debug easily is good code. Code you can read easily in 6 moths is even better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work

```
w=w.toUpperCase().replace(w.substring(1), w.substring(1).toLowerCase())
```

Because `w.substring(1)` isn't the same as `w.toUpperCase`.

Basically you have...

```
w = "MY NAME IS ALEX".replace("y Name Is Alex", "y name is alex");
```

As you can see, there's nothing for `String` to match against.  The upper case characters won't match the provided `String` value

Where as your double line method works more like...

```
 w=w.toUpperCase(); // "MY NAME IS ALEX"
 w="MY NAME IS ALEX".replace("Y NAME IS ALEX", "y name is alex");
```

`String` can no match the text.

Remember, these methods are case sensitve

Answer (score 1):

This one line of code wil work

```
w = w.toUpperCase().replace(w.toUpperCase().substring(1),
                    w.substring(1).toLowerCase());
```